# Can I do $in on specific pairs of fields?

Tags: mongodb

The following query:

```
db.mydoc.find({x:{$in:[1, 2, 3]}, y:{$in:[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}})
```

will find the records which can contain all the possible combinations of x and y. How do I modify the query so that I get only records which match corresponding x and y pairs, i.e., hypothetically:

```
db.mydoc.find({(x,y):{$in:[(1,0.1), (2,0.2), (3,0.3)]}})
```

I can certainly filter these out in post-processing, or query for each individual x, but is there a way to get it in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually becomes an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query like so:

```js
db.mydoc.find({
    "$or": [
        { "x": 1, "y": 0.1 },
        { "x": 2, "y": 0.2 },
        { "x": 3, "y": 0.3 }
    ]
})
```

So the logic now just selects the documents that match either of those specific criteria.